# How to get python to change strings to 2dcp

Tags: python

I can tell this has been answered in some way already, but I can't find a fix for it.
The problem is that I am trying to change the variable "price" to an str and format it to have 2 decimal places.
Here's the code:

```
def fin():
    while True:
        global price
        wantdrink = input("Would you like a drink? (We only server Coke): ")
        if wantdrink not in "Yes" "yes" "No" "no" "Yeah" "yeah" "Nah" "nah":
            wrong()
        elif wantdrink in "Yes" "yes" "Yeah" "yeah":
            print("Got to stay hydrated!")
            price = price + 0.50
            price = str(price)
            "{0:.2f}".format(price)
            print("Your order is complete! The total price is", price , "pounds")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Your order numbmer is:", num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Your food will be delivered in", timnum1 + timnum2, "minuites!")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Thanks for ordering from Hungry Horse(TM)!")
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
        elif wantdrink in "No" "no" "Nah" "nah":
            print("Don't get too thirsty!")
            price = str(price)
            "{0:.2f}".format(price)
            print("Your order is complete! The total price is", price, "pounds")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Your order numbmer is:", num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Your food will be delivered in", timnum1 + timnum2, "minuites!")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Thanks for ordering from Hungry Horse(TM)!")
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
```

This is only part of the program, Would showing the full thing help?

Anyway, when running the program python just displays:

> ```
> ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
> ```

Is there a way to fix this? Am I just being dumb? Please help...

Comment: Also, I want the decimals to convert like this:  1.5 --> 1.50

Comment: See [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/), in particular [Numbers](https://pyformat.info/#number)

Comment: Short answer to your immediate questions, "yes, there is, and yes, you kind of are". See below for more complete explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off Mad Physicists answer, you can bring the formatted price right into the line about the order being complete:

```
print("Your order is complete! The total price is {0:.2f} pounds.".format(price))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

The problem is that you don't have a number.  You already have a string.

Demonstration:

```
>>> price = 1
>>> type(price)
<class 'int'>
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(price)
'1.00'
>>> 
>>> price = 1.5
>>> type(price)
<class 'float'>
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(price)
'1.50'
>>> 
>>> price = '1.5'
>>> type(price)
<class 'str'>
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(price)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
>>>
```

Upon closer inspection of your code:

> ```
> price = str(price)
> "{0:.2f}".format(price)
> ```

You converted the number to a string without specifying any format: `str(price)`.  Then you attempted to format a string and did nothing with the return value.

To fix it:

```
price = "{0:.2f}".format(price)
```

---

---

By the way, it is very bad practice to use floating point data for prices.  You need to use a decimal or fixed-point type if you want accurate currency handling.  The reason is that base-2 and base-10 fractions don't line up perfectly.  This is well-documented and explained online.

Comment: Or use integers and pennies.

Answer (score 0):

You are pre-converting to a string using `str`. `format` already does that for you. Relpace

```
price = str(price)
"{0:.2f}".format(price)
```

with just

```
price = "{0:0.2f}".format(price)
```

Of course you can not print a string with two digits of floating point precision.

Comment: That is just leaving it as 1.5, I want it as 1.50

Comment: @martin4509. Fixed. Forgot the other zero.